# Значення слова "лярва"?

Tags: значення-слів

**Приклад вживання.**

> *"О, ця жінка! Ця розпусниця, негідниця, повія, профура, **ЛЯРВА**, лахудра, потіпаха, чорти б її за коси микали!"* ("Чотири дороги
>   назустріч." Леся Романчук)

***Лярва***...  В сучасному світі так називають поганих жінок, частіше старих. Багато режисерів експлуатують це слово в своїх фільмах на контрасті - хороша дівчина - погана дівчина.

> У слов'янської міфології ***Лярва*** - злобний жіночий дух, здатний
>   вселятися в тіло жінки, роблячи її розпусною.

**Що ж насправді означає дане слово?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Коротко кажучи, це слово запозичено з латини, скоріш за все через польську. Латинське *larva* «злий дух; привид, скелет; маска» пов'язане з *lar* «добрий дух, що охороняє», *Lares* «боги, душі померлих, що охороняють домашнє вогнище». Порівняйте англійське *larva*, яке теж запозичене з латини, від того самого слова, та означає «личинка комахи».
Зверніть увагу, що наше «личинка» походить від «личина», яке означає «маска», тобто наче і лице, та одночасно й не лице.
«Етимологічний словник української мови» в 7 томах [у томі 3](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.djvu) (1989) на сторінці 342 пише про походження слова «лярва» наступне:

[image]